# How to focus input field by default in Webview in flutter without any user interaction

Tags: javascript, angular, flutter, webview, flutter-inappwebview

I am using [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) to open webview in flutter app.

My use case is, I want to open keyboard as soon as user enters in the webview. The page that I am loading in webview already has a focused input field but the keyboard does not open automatically.
I have to tap on the input field (in the page) in order to open the keyboard. If I load the same page on web-browser, it works fine and shows focused (with cursor) input field.

Some observation that I had - If I interact with web-view and come back to that page, keyboard opens up automatically. So it seems, we have to do some user interaction (real, not programatically) in order to focus element in page.

How to focus by default the webview to let me programmatically set the focus on a specific webview input? Or Is there any thing that can be done in web-page to open keyboard? Thanks in advance.

I have tried everything in web-page to open the keyboard like adding focus only when page is fully loaded. This was done in web-page, not from flutter side. But it does not open the keyboard, just leaves the input field in focused state (but cursor does not appear).